# How to add Items to a Single Dictionary from Multiple For Loops?

Tags: python, csv, beautifulsoup

> I started Learning Python Recently. What I am basically doing is Scraping data from Website and adding to a list of dictionaries ,
> This is what the final structure should look like :

> This is basically my scraping code. I had to use `two for loops` since , the element to target are present at different positions on the webpage(**One for Title and Another for Description**)

```
jobslist=[]
    for item in title:
        MainTitle = item.text
        mydict = {
        'title' : MainTitle,
        }
    jobslist.append(mydict)

for i in link:
    links = i['href']
    r2 = requests.get(links, headers = headers)
    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(r2.content,'lxml')
    entry_content = soup2.find('div', class_ ='entry-content')
    mydict= {
    'description' : entry_content
    }
jobslist.append(mydict)
```

> Finally Saving to a CSV (pandas library used where pd is the import)

```
df = pd.DataFrame(jobslist)
df.to_csv('data.csv')
```

> But, the Output is quite strange. The description are added below the Titles and not side by side. This is the Screenshot :
> [image]

> How can I align it side by side ?

Comment: You should consider dumping what the data looks like in jobslist -- I don't see where you're referencing the first data set in the assignment of the second.  This isn't about the CSV, its about the data structure in jobslist.

Answer (score 1):

*Disclaimer: It's hard to give a perfect answer because your code is not reproducible; I have no idea what your date looks like, nor what you're trying to do, so I can't really test anything.*

From what I understand of your code, it looks like the dictionaries are completely unnecessary. You have a list of titles, and a list of descriptions. So be it:

```py
titles_list = []
    for item in title:
        titles_list.append(item.text)

descriptions_list = []
for i in link:
    links = i['href']
    r2 = requests.get(links, headers = headers)
    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(r2.content,'lxml')
    entry_content = soup2.find('div', class_ ='entry-content')
    descriptions_list.append(entry_content)

df = pd.DataFrame(data = {'title': titles_list, 'description': descriptions_list}) # here we use a dict of lists instead of a list of dicts
df.to_csv('data.csv')
```

Comment: trying and letting you know. Did i miss something in the question ? I tried to make it minimal

Comment: Getting Error : ValueError: arrays must all be same length

Comment: @Sainita Yes, this code assumes that you have the same number of titles and descriptions, and that descriptions should be aligned with titles in the same order.

Comment: @Sainita Well, the code in your question refers to two variables `title` and `link` which I don't have, so I can't reproduce it.

Comment: should i upload complete to pastebin and give you a link ?

Comment: @Sainita Maybe you could just print `jobslist`?

Comment: Sir, I uploaded to pastebin. Also, made the changes you suggested. Pls see here : https://pastebin.com/wvWW6u6A